# Parse Javascript output array / Parse URL Hash

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, hash, split

I'm trying to parse out a single value from a URL String with three varaibles, and I am currently using the code:

```
var hash_array = location.hash.substring(1).split('&');
var hash_key_val = new Array(hash_array.length);

for (var i = 0; i < hash_array.length; i++) {
hash_key_val[i] = hash_array[i].split('=');
var array = hash_key_val[i];
console.log(array);
}
```

This code works to parse out the hash, but it creates separate arrays for each item and value like so:

```
["object1", "value1"]
["object2", "value2"]
["object3", "value3"]
```

By altering the array to `var x = JSON.stringify(array[1]);`

I can get the value which is all I need, but I only need the first value, while this code still returns:

```
"value1"
"value2"
"value3"
```

How can I alter the code so that the function only outputs `value1`?

Thanks!

Comment: can you tell me what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the 1 for 0; Arrays start at zero index. Also I am not sure if you are aware that you are looping over the values as you are printing them out.

```js
var arr = [
  ["object1", "value1"],
  ["object2", "value2"],
  ["object3", "value3"]
];

console.log(arr[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Arrow mentioned you need to change the index at which you access `array` from 1 to 0.

Additionally, why not use map:

```
var keys = hash_array.map(function(param){
    return JSON.stringify(param.split('=')[0]);
}
```

with keys being `["object1", "object2", "object3"]`